# Change table row size to another table row size

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a table1 in one sheet that is feeded through a SQL Command, i have another table2 in another sheet that makes references to table1. I need table2 to resize the number of rows according to table1, how can i do that (Hopefully without VBA)?

Table2 is a table which has a calculated column and then every other column are table1 columns.

My references in table2 are like this:

`calc(table1[column1]) table1[column1] table1[column2] ....`

**Note:** I have tried using @ in the column reference but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it using VBA, so until anyone posts here a VBAless solution here is what you need to do:

1. Create a named range which we will call `range1` on the **formulas menu -> name manager**

   =OFFSET('table2'!$A$1,0,0,ROWS(table1[#All]),COLUMNS(table2[#All]))
2. Go to VBA and create the following sub:

   ```
   Sub ResizeMyTable()

       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").ListObjects("table2").Resize [range1]

   End Sub
   ```

The following logic is up to you, i created a button and did a `call ResizeMyTable` to update the table.